# $L$ and $L_{\omega_2}$ agree on all $\Sigma_1$ formulae?

Tags: set-theory

I remember seeing this mentioned somewhere in a textbook I was looking at a while ago, but I can't seem to find the proof. Is anyone aware of the reference I'm looking for? Or can someone provide a quick sketch of the proof?

Comment: I suppose $\Sigma_1$ would refer to the [Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: **condensation**!

Here's a quick sketch of a stronger theorem - that $\Sigma_1$ truth is absolute between $L$ and $L_\kappa$ for any uncountable cardinal $\kappa$:

- First, show that the $L$-hierarchy preserves *bounded* statements. That is, if $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_0$-sentence with parameters from $L_\alpha$, and $\alpha<\beta$, then $L_\alpha\models\varphi$ iff $L_\beta\models\varphi$. (This is basically because $L_\beta$ is an *end extension* of $L_\alpha$.)
- Next, suppose $\psi$ is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence with parameters from $L_\kappa$ ($\kappa$ an uncountable cardinal); that is, $\psi\equiv \exists x\theta(x)$ for some $\Sigma_0$ formula $\theta$ with parameters from $L_\kappa$. If $L_\kappa\models\psi$, then $L_\kappa\models\theta(a)$ for some $a\in L_\kappa$; but this is a bounded statement, so true in $L$ as well.
- So finally, assume everything is as above but $L\models\psi$ instead of $L_\kappa\models\psi$. Here things get interesting. Let $b\in L$ be a witness to $\psi$ - that is, $L\models\theta(b)$. Now $b$ might not exist in $L_\kappa$; we'll fix that. Specifically, all the parameters in $\psi$ occur at some level $\theta$ of the $L$-hierarchy for $\theta<\kappa$ (why?); so take an elementary substructure $M$ of $L$, containing $L_\theta$ as a subset and $b$ as an element, of cardinality $<\kappa$ (why does this exist?). What does condensation tell you about $M$? Do you see how to use the absoluteness of bounded statements to finish the proof?

---

Here's a good exercise: clearly $L_{\omega_2}$ and $L$ disagree about $\Sigma_2$-truth - e.g. consider the sentence "there exist two uncountable cardinals." So where does the proof above break down if I try to get $\Sigma_2$-agreement?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the argument naturally splits into two important parts. Firstly, if $\kappa$ is any uncountable cardinal then $H_\kappa$ and $V$ agree on $\Sigma_1$-truth (this is due to Levy), and secondly, $L_\kappa=H_\kappa^L$ for any $L$-cardinal $\kappa$ (this uses condensation).

Comment: I find the part where you mention 'end extensions' a bit misleading. It suffices to note that $L_\alpha \subseteq L_\beta$ and both are transitive.